# if statement using && for two floats?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a c# script in Unity and have an issue. I'm trying to check if two floats equal to zero for a countdown timer. once both reach zero, do something.

when i do

```
if (minutes && seconds <= 0){
        Debug.Log("countdown timer has finished");
    }
```

I get the error;

> error CS0019: Operator `&&' cannot be applied to operands of type`float' and `bool'

I understand what's going on here, my question is how can I check if both floats reach zero, debug.Log.

Comment: _I'm trying to check if two floats equal to zero_ You are not doing that in your code. You just checked `seconds` is less or equal to zero, not `minutes`. The `&&` operators expect boolean expression in both side.

Comment: why are minutes and seconds floats ? I would simply make them unsigned  ints.

Comment: What you're actually doing is checking if `minutes` is true and if `seconds` is <= 0.  `minutes` is not a `bool` (i.e. it doesn't have a true / false value) hence the error.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck - signed ints surely? The `<= 0` part implies that the timer could go below zero... (i.e. after the point in time had passed)

Comment: @colmde depends on the implementation if they need to be signed yes or no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't check more than one variables like that. You must change your code:

```
if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0){
        Debug.Log("countdown timer has finished");
    }
```

Or, if you have many variables to check like that, then you can create new List and use `Any()` method from th `System.Linq` namespace. (***But,*** *as @Marc commented if you have not a list yet, then it is not recommended*):

```
if (!(new[] { firstFloat, secondFloat, thirdFloat }).Any(x => x > 0));
```

But, if you have a list or an array, it would be much better and simpler:

```
if (!myList.Any(x => x > 0));
```

Comment: newing a list (or an array) is *massively* overkill for a single-predicate test, IMO; if you already have the list and contents: fine

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't provide any syntax to combine application of single condition / operators on many variables directly in "if" condition (but of course you could do that with functions).

You have to test separately each condition :

```
if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0)
{
   Debug.Log("countdown timer has finished");
}
```

You can also use a nicer datatype to handle all "time" related tests, such as Timespan, or even a "total seconds count" single variable. It's sounds strange to have separate "seconds" and "minutes" variables.

Answer (score 0):

In C# You cannot do float comparison like this. In C++, boolean true is treated as non-zero value and for false it's zero. That's why we can directly compare the float value with in if condition. But in C# you have to specify the full condition.

```
if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0){
        Debug.Log("countdown timer has finished");
    }
```